# ¿Cómo diseñar un modelo de Base de datos para inicio de sesión?

Tags: base-de-datos, mariadb

Este modelo de base de datos ya está hecho. Lo desearía hacer con este modelo, es permitir iniciar sesión a alumnos y a maestro y con el inicio de sesión determinar las funciones del sistema a la que puede acceder el usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber como hacer una tabla usuarios y relacionarla con las otras 2 tablas (Alumno y Maestro), para saber que funciones puede realizar el usuario que inicio sesión en el sistema

Comment: No entiendo nada de lo que escribiste, ¿estas preguntando como hacer una tabla "usuario" y relacionarla con las otras tablas?

Comment: Ya hice la correción del problema, crees que está bien diseñado el modelo E-R?

Comment: Seria bueno que indique en las etiquetas a que motor de base de datos apuntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizas para algunas personas tu pregunta pueda ser demasiado trivial, pero pienso que es una pregunta válida y la responderé.

En este caso, puedes ver que en ambas tablas (profesor y alumno) hay campos repetidos, que sería el usuario y la contraseña. La idea de normalizar una base de datos es, en uno de sus puntos, evitar esta repetición de campos.

Lo que podrías hacer es crear una nueva tabla con la información del usuario como tal y relacionarla a las otras dos tablas. (Hice un pequeño ejemplo en el primer sitio online que encontre, porque no estoy en mi computadora de siempre)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves, ahora solo se guarda una sola vez el usuario y la contraseña, y puedes llegar a esta información por la relación que existe. Incluso puedes añadirle un campo `rol` a esa tabla para que puedas definir que acciones puede tomar cada uno de los profesores o alumnos.